# Normalize away unnecessary `Compose` and `Identity` nested in a type

Tags: haskell

I'd like to define a type which contains a container and a type for the container, and some operations, like one to perform an outer-product on the containers, one to map the container and its value, as well as everything offered by various standard classes (`Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, `MonadTrans` etc).

This is the definition of the type and the two operations I mentioned:

```hs
-- metacontainer
newtype MC c a = MC { runMetaContainer :: c a } deriving Show

-- outer product
cross :: (Functor f1, Functor f2) => (a -> b -> c) -> MC f1 a -> MC f2 b
  -> MC (Compose f1 f2) c
cross f (MC c1) (MC c2) = MC $ Compose $ (\x -> f x <$> c2) <$> c1

-- map the container
hoist :: (c1 a -> c2 b) -> MC c1 a -> MC c2 b
hoist f (MC c) = MC $ f c
```

This stuff works, however when I `cross` two `MC`s, the resulting container is made of some nested *unnecessary* containers, such as `Compose` or `Identity`. I wish to get rid of them somehow.

See this example:

```hs
let list = MC [1,2,3]          :: MC [] Int
let justStr = MC $ Just "hey"  :: MC Maybe String
let n = MC $ Identity 5        :: MC Identity Int

let dblLst = cross (*) list n  :: MC (Compose [] Identity) Int
let justStrList = cross (\x str -> str ++ " " ++ show x)
  dblLst justStr               :: MC (Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe) String
```

Because of those unnecessary `Compose`s and `Identity`s in `justStrList`'s type, I cannot simply do something like...

```hs
hoist (\lstMbStr -> lstMbStr & filter isJust & map fromJust) justStrList
-- error
--     • Couldn't match type ‘Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe’
--                      with ‘[]’
--       Expected: MyType [] (Maybe b0)
--         Actual: MyType (Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe) String
```

Is there any way to *normalize* a container?

In case of the example I'd like to turn the `(Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe) String` into the equivalent `[Maybe String]`.

---

I tried to use Li-yao Xia's solution, but it's not working for me.

This is my entire code:

```hs
import Data.Maybe ( catMaybes )
import Data.Functor.Identity ( Identity(..) )
import Data.Functor.Compose ( Compose, Compose(..) )
import Data.Coerce (coerce, Coercible)

-- metacontainer
newtype MC c a = MC { runMetaContainer :: c a }

-- outer product
cross :: (Functor f1, Functor f2) => (a -> b -> c) -> MC f1 a -> MC f2 b
  -> MC (Compose f1 f2) c
cross f (MC c1) (MC c2) = MC $ Compose $ (\x -> f x <$> c2) <$> c1

-- map the container
hoist :: (c1 a -> c2 b) -> MC c1 a -> MC c2 b
hoist f (MC c) = MC $ f c

coerceMC :: Coercible (c a) (d a) => MC c a -> MC d a
coerceMC = coerce

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let list = MC [1,2,3]
    let justStr = MC $ Just "hey"
    let n = MC $ Identity 5

    let dblLst = cross (*) list n
    let justStrList = cross (\x str -> str ++ " " ++ show x) dblLst justStr
    
    print $ hoist catMaybes (coerceMC justStrList)
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type: [Char]
                     with: Maybe b0
      Expected: MC (Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe) (Maybe b0)
        Actual: MC (Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe) [Char]
    • In the first argument of ‘coerceMC’, namely ‘justStrList’
      In the second argument of ‘hoist’, namely ‘(coerceMC justStrList)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘hoist catMaybes (coerceMC justStrList)’
```

If I try to ask GHC for the type of `coerceMC justStrList`, it says it's `MC d0 [Char]` where ‘d0’ is an ambiguous type variable.

If I try to enable the `PartialTypeSignatures` extension, it says that it can't match representation of type: `[Identity (Maybe [Char])]` with that of: `d0 [Char]`.

I wouldn't know how to express by myself the type that I wish `coerceMC justStrList` has. It would be `MC [Maybe] String`, except that it's not a valid type due to mismatching kinds.

I tried to coerce the container inside of the hoist function (`hoist f (MC c) = MC $ f $ coerce c`) since I would know how to express the coercion for `c` (from `Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe String` to `[Maybe String]`), but it still doesn't work.

I managed to get it to work with this definition of `hoist`: `hoist f (MC c) = MC $ f (coerce c :: [Maybe String])`, but I wish to find a solution that can infer the coercion type from the type of `f`, if it can exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coerce` to map between types with the same run-time representation.

```
import Data.Coerce (coerce, Coercible)

-- Example specialization
example :: MC (Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe) a -> MC (Compose [] Maybe) a
example = coerce
```

`coerce` is very polymorphic and usually requires type annotations. The following specialization may help by fixing some of the type parameters:

```
coerceMC :: Coercible (c a) (d a) => MC c a -> MC d a
coerceMC = coerce
```

Your example still requires a bit more complexity. The type of `justStrList` is `MC (Compose (Compose [] Identity) Maybe) String`, which simplifies to `MC (Compose [] Maybe) String`, still with some `Compose` left, and this cannot really be simplified further.

Indeed, that last `Compose` can only be eliminated in `hoist`, just before applying the given function. It's a bit tricky to find a nice enough generalization of `hoist`. I would opt for this one, that just takes some conversion functions surrounding the main one.

```
hoistBetween :: (c1 a -> x) -> (y -> c2 b) -> (x -> y) -> MC c1 a -> MC c2 b
hoistBetween f h g (MC c) = MC $ h (g (f c))
```

You probably do not want both to be `coerce` because of the type inference issues mentioned earlier. A more specialized combinator which applies `coerce` on once side would have an ugly, asymmetrical signature. So `hoistBetween` it is.

You can now write this:

```
    print (hoistBetween coerce id catMaybes justStrList :: MC [] String)
```

This still requires a type signature on the result, because `print` is polymorphic, but in more substantial examples you can probably rely on both sides of `hoistBetween` to be known.

Alternatively, this `hoistBetween` lets you also just use the newtype constructors and destructors, avoiding the type inference issues of `coerce` (for a bit of overhead).

```
    print (hoistBetween
             (fmap runIdentity . getCompose . getCompose)
             id
             catMaybes
             justStrList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about `coerce` nor about `catMaybes`. However the solution you suggest doesn't work for me. I'm not sure what GHC's error means. I'm about to update the original post to include the complete code I tried and the error I receive.

Comment: I see it's a bit more subtle than I thought. I updated my answer with a working solution.